# Problems with location permission on android [EXPO| REACT NATIVE]

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-permissions, user-permissions

I'm trying to update an app that has already been published on the PlayStore but is now being refused because GOOGLE informs that the app does not respect usage policies. I receive the following message:

***- The app does not comply with the Location Permissions policy***

[Email with details send by google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSRRY.png)

After receiving this response from Google, I have already corrected my code, but the app continues to be refused.

Below are the actions I have already taken to try to resolve the issue:

- When I received the lock for the first time, I made the requested corrections in the application code. The app currently requests the following permissions:

[permissions on code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCLXB.png)

Below is the print of the permissions after uploading the .aab to the playstore:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJU9k.png)

- Accessing the play store policy menu, I noticed that the privacy policy setting is linked to build number 29 but I'm already trying to send build 35.

This build 29 uses background localization, but I can't unlink it from the policy configuration tab or add another app version.

[app settings in play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPZZH.png)

[wrong permissions in build 29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKA0c.png)

I've also reviewed the features that use localization in the code and everything is fine. Below screenshots of the code:

[code snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8BiF.png)

[code snippet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCOvt.png)

[code snippet 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tM1H.png)

I would like to know if anyone has had similar problems and can give me some guidance on how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I noticed that you wrote "ACCCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" (with 3 C). I don't know if this is the error, but better spell it right.

Second thing, be sure that you declared that you DON'T use background location. To do that, go to your Google Play Console, select your app, then go to

App Content (it should be the last section on the left) -> API and sensitive authorizations -> Manage

then set "No" to the question regarding background location.

This is the screen you should see after these steps

[image]